# How to reach multiple elements in an array without using axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Yesterday i saw a React project on youtube and i wanted to test it myself.

This function connects to the link and returns me the questions of the category and difficulty I selected with my buttons . code works fine ,but i don't want to do that step with axios and any API related stuff.

```
const fetchQuestions = async (category = "", difficulty = "") => {
const { data } = await axios.get(
  `https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10${
    category && `&category=${category}`                  
  }${difficulty && `&difficulty=${difficulty}`}&type=multiple`
);
  console.log(category);
  console.log(difficulty);

setQuestions(data.results);};
```

I only want to see the questions in the difficulty and category I chose .
So i created a json file and tried to get those questions&answers etc. with that but it didn't work . I tried to map things inside and log category and difficulty but i can't even reach those . I know that i need some conditions etc. but i can't create the logic .

```
const fetchQuestions =(category="",difficulty="")=>{const {data}=QuestionList.results.map((q)=> (console.log(category),console.log(q[category]),console.log(data),console.log(q[difficulty]))); setQuestions(data.results);}
```

this is json file : questions.json   ->    i imported as QuestionList

```
{
"response_code": 0,
"results": [
  {
    "category": "Books",
    "type": "multiple",
    "difficulty": "medium",
    "question": "some question?",
    "correct_answer": "blabla",
    "incorrect_answers": ["Transformers", "Care Bears", "Rubik&rsquo;s Cube"]
  },
  {
    "category": "Books",
    "type": "multiple",
    "difficulty": "easy",
    "question": "sdklgksdflgjsdf",
    "correct_answer": "Badminton",
    "incorrect_answers": ["Table Tennis", "Rugby", "Cricket"]
  },
  {
    "category": "Books",
    "type": "multiple",
    "difficulty": "medium",
    "question": "fgdfgdfgdfgdfgg?",
    "correct_answer": "9",
    "incorrect_answers": ["6", "10", "3"]
  },
  {
    "category": "Films",
    "type": "multiple",
    "difficulty": "medium",
    "question": "asdasdasdasd",
    "correct_answer": "Parlor",
    "incorrect_answers": ["Open Room", "Sitting Room", "Loft"]
  },
  {
    "category": "Films",
    "type": "multiple",
    "difficulty": "medium",
    "question": "asdasdasddddd",
    "correct_answer": "Link",
    "incorrect_answers": ["Wario", "Q*bert", "Solid Snake"]
  }
]}
```

I've been stuck on this for 9 hours but i still have no solution :)

Comment: It depends on additional frameworks used. If you use webpack then you can use Webpack copy plugin to copy the JSON file into a static folder that gets served to the client and then you could do something like fetch("static/questions.json") to get the questions from json.  https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/fetch-data-from-a-json-file-in-a-react-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

> ```
> const fetchQuestions = (category = "", difficulty = "") => {
>   const { data } = QuestionList.results.map(
>     (q) => (
>       console.log(category),
>       console.log(q[category]),
>       console.log(data),
>       console.log(q[difficulty])
>     )
>   );
>   setQuestions(data.results);
> };
> ```

The code above is calling the `Array.prototype.map` function but the callback is returning a Comma Operator expression and the last operand's return value is what is returned. `console..log` is a void return, however, so `undefined` is returned as the map value. On top of the, `.map` returns an array, not an object, so there's no `data` property to destructure from the mapped array. Later accessing `data.results` is likely throwing a TypeError, something to effect of "cannot access 'results' of undefined".

## Solution

If I understand your question correctly you have just created a local `questionList` JSON file that is imported and you are wanting to filter the results by some search criteria.

Example:

```
const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([]);

const fetchQuestions = (category = "", difficulty = "") => {
  const data = questionList.results.filter(
    (question) =>
      question.category.toLowerCase().includes(category.toLowerCase()) &&
      question.difficulty.toLowerCase().includes(difficulty.toLowerCase())
  );
  setQuestions(data);
};

useEffect(() => {
  fetchQuestions();
}, []);
```

- `fetchQuestions();` - returns all 5 results
- `fetchQuestions("books");` - returns the 3 "books" category entries
- `fetchQuestions("", "easy");` - returns the 1 "easy" difficulty entry

[image: Edit how-to-reach-multiple-elements-in-an-array-without-using-axios]

Comment: First of all thanks alot for this solution,it did work and when i call fetchQuestions(); function in my Home component it shows all questions and quiz also works fine. if i change the function as fetchQuestions("books"); it shows questions about books , How can i make this more dynamic ? Right now i have `<select value={category} onChange={(e) => setCategory(e.target.value)}>
{Categories.map((cat) => (<option key={cat.category} value={cat.value}>{cat.category}
 </option>))}` this for my categories and i have a button witch calls handleSubmit fonction(i have fetchQuestions function in there)

Comment: `const handleSubmit = () => {fetchQuestions();};    return ( <div className="settings_select"><select value={category} onChange={(e) => setCategory(e.target.value)}>{Categories.map((cat) => (<option key={cat.category} value={cat.value}> {cat.category} </option>))}<select onChange={(e) => setDifficulty(e.target.value)} value={difficulty}><option key="Easy" value="easy">
easy</option><option key="Medium" value="medium"> medium
</option> </select>
          <button className="button" onClick={handleSubmit}>Start Quiz</button>
     </div>` my code is looks like that  @Drew Reese

Comment: @SercanKuduscu Sorry, I thought the focus of your question was about the initial display, so I didn't include any dynamic filtering. That all looks correct, or really close if it's not quite working. Here's a [forked sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-reach-multiple-elements-in-an-array-without-using-axios-forked-h53lj3?file=/src/App.js) of my above code with a form and inputs.

Comment: You are the best man , you can't imagine how much this one helped me . Thanks alot ! :)